# Test with imperative xfail in py.test always reports as xfail even if the passes

Tags: pytest

I always thought that imperative and declarative usage of xfail/skip in py.test should work in the same way. In the meantime I've noticed that if I write a test that contains an imperative skip the result of the test will always be "xfail" even it the test passes.

Here's some code:

```
import pytest

def test_should_fail():
    pytest.xfail("reason")

@pytest.mark.xfail(reason="reason")
def test_should_fail_2():
    assert 1
```

Running these tests will always result in:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.3.5 -- C:\Python27\python.exe
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_xfail.py:3: test_should_fail xfail
test_xfail.py:6: test_should_fail_2 XPASS

===================== 1 xfailed, 1 xpassed in 0.02 seconds =====================
```

If I understand correctly what is written in the [user manual](http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html), both test should be "XPASS'ed".

Is this a bug in py.test or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `pytest.xfail()` helper function you are effectively raising an exception in the test function.  Only when you are using the marker it is possible for py.test to execute the test fully and give you an XPASS.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still wondering what should be the outcome of `$ py.test --runxfail`? First test is always Failed even if it has `assert 1`. Second test is normally is executed, which is fine.

Comment: Using `--runxfail` will make py.test print the exception of the failed test.  Furthermore if you used `@pytest.mark.xfail(run=False)` to not run the marked test by default `--runxfail` will run it anway.